# Any __future__ import for range-xrange incompatibility?

Tags: python

Writting for Python 2, I always use `xrange`, but it is renamed in Python 3.
So I mostly write

```
if sys.version.startswith('3'):
    zrange = range
else:
    zrange = xrange
```

and use `zrange` below. Is there a more graceful solution (without depending on 3rd party package), like `from __future__ import unicode_literal` hopefully?

Comment: You should take a look at [six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

Comment: No there is no future import, if you want it a little more concise `zrange = range if sys.version.startswith('3') else xrange`

Answer (score 14):

No, there is no `from __future__` import for this, nor do you need to use a third-party package. Simply catch the name error when `xrange` is not available:

```
try:
    zrange = xrange
except NameError:
    zrange = range
```

There's not really a need to test for versions.

Personally, I'd not make up a new name, just re-use `range` on Python 2:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    range = xrange
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    pass
```

or add `xrange` in Python 3 as an alias:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    xrange
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    xrange = range
```

Re-assigning `range` in Python 2 only is preferable, since going forward a project is far more likely to drop Python 2 support and focus on Python 3 syntax exclusively than the other way around.

Packages that need to support both Python 2 and Python 3 usually create a `compat` module to handle bridges like these. See the [`requests.compat` module](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py) for example, where they do use a version test only because that limits the number of tests to just the one `if`.

Comment: Was going to write the same but not sure this is really any *more graceful* than the OP's own code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: if `range` is the *only thing* they need to bridge then I prefer to use the exception handler. If there are more tests perhaps a version check is in order, in a dedicated `compat` module.

Comment: I think  the OP is simply looking for something that does not exist.